# DocumentDB paging with many collections

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Lets say I have two collections and there are 10 documents in each collection. What is the recommended way to do paging if i want to retrive max 15 documents?

When I run the code below I get 20 results. It begins requesting the first collection which returnes 10 and then the second which also returns 10 but it should return 5 since the MaxItemCount is 15.

```
        var batches = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = 15
        };

        var docQuery = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Database.SelfLink, feedOptions)
                 .Where(predicate).AsDocumentQuery();

        do
        {
            var batch = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
            batches.Add(batch);

        } while (docQuery.HasMoreResults);

        var docs = batches.SelectMany(b => b).Take(maxItemCount.Value);

        return docs;
```

Answer (score 3):

MaxItemCount controls the number of results per page, not the total results returned. To reduce the total number of results, change your while clause to check for e.g., (docQuery.HasMoreResults &&  batch.Length <= maxItemCount.Value).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried this with same result. The problem is when the data is in more than one collection. When in this example (MaxItemCount = 15) it has retrieved the 10 from the first collection, it should only retrieve 5 from the other but it also retrieves 10.

Comment: To do this, you must manage the collection iteration and paging in the client side. i.e., call client.ResolveForRead() and enumerate the collection self links. Then within each collection, call ExecuteNextAsync() and set the MaxItemCount to Math.Min(maxItemCount.value - batch.Length, 15)